# SQL Server where query not working after join and new column

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

This is my current working query:

```
DECLARE @ProductName AS VARCHAR(400) 

SET @ProductName = 'water'
SET @ProductName = CONCAT('\"',@ProductName,'\"') 

SELECT 
    *,
    distance = GEOGRAPHY::Point(42, -90, 4326).STDistance(GEOGRAPHY::Point(latitude, longitude, 4326)) / 1609.344 
FROM 
    products AS FT_TBL 
INNER JOIN 
    FREETEXTTABLE(products, product_name, @ProductName) AS KEY_TBL ON FT_TBL.id = KEY_TBL.[key] 
WHERE 
    KEY_TBL.RANK >= 10 
ORDER BY 
    KEY_TBL.RANK DESC, distance ASC
```

I'm trying to add a check for `distance < 20` before doing the join but it's not working no matter what I do, I get an error

> Invalid column name 'distance'

even if I try inside of the where query.

How can I do this in an efficient manner before I even do the join?

Comment: Put it in a subquery. An aside: this might be interesting from @BrentOzar [Why Full Text’s CONTAINS Queries Are So Slow](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2020/11/why-full-texts-contains-queries-are-so-slow/)

Comment: thanks for the link but no thanks for the unhelpful advice

Comment: What did you find unhelpful about it? I believe it is the same as the accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use subquery first to actually create the table with `distance` column before include it in where clause.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT *,
distance = GEOGRAPHY::Point(42, -90, 4326).STDistance(GEOGRAPHY::Point(latitude, longitude, 4326)) / 1609.344 
FROM products ) AS FT_TBL 
INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(products, product_name, @ProductName) AS KEY_TBL ON FT_TBL.id = KEY_TBL.[key] 
WHERE KEY_TBL.RANK >= 10 AND distance < 20 ORDER BY KEY_TBL.RANK DESC ,distance asc
```

this should work just fine.

Comment: can you please show me how im not familiar with subquerys

Comment: you can not include `distance` column in where clause, think like this way, `where` is a filter statement which filter the data you want, so it can't filter something isn't there yet. But with subquery you already make a "table" with `distance` column so it will be fine to put it in the `where` clause.